# Any code on ALE method for N-S equations or advection-diffusion equations?

Tags: finite-element, fluid-dynamics, space-time-galerkin

I'm currently reading the book **computational fluid-structure interaction**, but the book doesn't provide any code, and I can't understand the ALE method, could you please provide some codes written in python by using external libraries on ALE or space-time stabilized SUPG method? thank you

Comment: https://github.com/lanl/Harmony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some open source codes using ALE-based fluid-structure interaction:

- FSI tutorial in deal.II: https://github.com/tommeswick/fsi
- FSI library in FEniCS: https://github.com/KVSlab/turtleFSI
- short FSI code in FEniCS: https://github.com/ottarph/learnext-correction-FSI/blob/NN-corrected/FSIsolver/fsi_solver/solver_full.py

Comment: Additionally here are some lecture notes on Fluid-Structure Interaction by Prof. Thomas Wick: http://www.thomaswick.org/links/lecture_notes_FSI_Nov_28_2019.pdf